# Looping thru array, passing data to function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having some trouble getting this to work.

```
var Browser = require('zombie');
var browser = new Browser({
 debug: true
})



function getPredictions(){
    var prediction = ['5', '7', '9', '11', '14', '18'];
    for(i in prediction){
        sendPrediction(prediction[i]);
    }
}

function sendPrediction(prediction){
    browser.visit('http://localhost:3000/prediction.php', function (error, browser){
        browser.fill('#prediction', prediction);
        browser.pressButton('Send', function (error, browser){
            if(browser.html == 'correct'){
                console.log('The correct prediction is ' + prediction +'');
            }else{
                console.log('The prediction ' + prediction + ' is incorrect.');
            }
        });
    });
}

getPredictions();
```

Basically, all four predictions I pass over from the array to my server, I want to be able to check if it's the correct prediction. '9' is the correct prediction, however it tells me that all of them are invalid even if browser.html is 'correct'.

How can I get this to work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the code looks fine - we don't know what `prediction.php` is doing however

Comment: As Otto said, the code looks fine (other than using `for..in` to loop through an array without any safeguards on it, see *[Myths and realities of `for..in`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)*).

Comment: Prediction just returns correct or incorrect, however when I run it, it returns either all incorrect or all correct, not with one correct.

Comment: Oh, and you're not declaring `i`, which means you're falling prey to The Horror of Implicit Globals. But I wouldn't expect that to be the actual problem either.

Comment: Can you confirm, that proper value is being passed to `sendPrediction` function?

Comment: Do a console log for browser.html and for (typeof browser.html), you are either getting the wrong value back or you are not comparing correctly. And you should probably do sendPrediction(i) instead of sendPrediction(prediction[i]). Or you can do a for loop like this: for(var i=0; i<prediction.length; i++) { sendPrediction(prediction[i]);

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help everyone. It was a cookie issue and 'browser' was being declared outside of the sendPrediction function. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your are reusing a same instance of zombie-browser. Try to rewrite your code this way.   Now the `getPrediction` method will "wait" until previous one is completed and parsed (note the `next` argument).

```
function getPredictions(){
    var i = -1, prediction = ['5', '7', '9', '11', '14', '18'];
    var next = function() {
        i++;
        if(i < prediction.length)
            sendPrediction(prediction[i], next);
    }
    next();
}

function sendPrediction(prediction, next){
    browser.visit('http://localhost:3000/prediction.php', function (error, browser){
        browser.fill('#prediction', prediction);
        browser.pressButton('Send', function (error, browser){
            if(browser.html == 'correct'){
                console.log('The correct prediction is ' + prediction +'');
            }else{
                console.log('The prediction ' + prediction + ' is incorrect.');
            }
            next();
        });
    });
}
```

Also you may try to create a new `Browser` instance each time you checking a prediction

```
function sendPrediction(prediction){
    var browser = new Browser({ debug: true });
    browser.visit('http://localhost:3000/prediction.php', function (error, browser){
        browser.fill('#prediction', prediction);
        browser.pressButton('Send', function (error, browser){
            if(browser.html == 'correct'){
                console.log('The correct prediction is ' + prediction +'');
            }else{
                console.log('The prediction ' + prediction + ' is incorrect.');
            }
        });
    });
}
```